# How to implement infinite scroll using native JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, infinite-scroll

How do I implement infinite/endless scrolling(like Facebook) in my project **without any libraries or frameworks**?

Almost all guides show how to do this with `jQuery`, `React` and `Angular` but I want a native JavaScript implementation for infinite scrolling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an infinite/endless scrolling code snippet written in native JavaScript:

```
window.onscroll = function () {
    if (window.scrollY > (document.body.offsetHeight - window.outerHeight)) {
        console.log("It's working!");                            
    }
}
```

To add a delay to this function execution(if you are sending requests to a server this is a must) you can write it like this:

```
window.onscroll = infiniteScroll;

    // This variable is used to remember if the function was executed.
    var isExecuted = false;

    function infiniteScroll() {
        // Inside the "if" statement the "isExecuted" variable is negated to allow initial code execution.
        if (window.scrollY > (document.body.offsetHeight - window.outerHeight) && !isExecuted) {
            // Set "isExecuted" to "true" to prevent further execution
            isExecuted = true;

            // Your code goes here
            console.log("Working...");

            // After 1 second the "isExecuted" will be set to "false" to allow the code inside the "if" statement to be executed again
            setTimeout(() => {
                isExecuted = false;
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
```

I use it in my `ASP.NET MVC 5` project and it works like a charm.

**Note:**
This code snippet doesn't work on some browsers(I'm looking at you IE). The `window.scrollY` property is `undefined` on IE.

Comment: @SaifTaher sorry to hear that. Are you sure you implemented it correctly? You need enough height  to be able to scroll in order to trigger the `onscroll` event.

Comment: You said that it works with ASP.NET though... Maybe that's the problem??!! (I don't really think so)

Comment: @SaifTaher what browser are you using? I'm using Google Chrome. `window.onscroll` event may not work properly on IE, Opera and Safari. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onscroll#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @SaifTaher I can confirm that the code snippet works on Opera as well. On IE it's broken.

Comment: Weird I'm using Chrome too... Maybe I didn't implement it correctly, though: I tested it on JS Bin not in a proper HTML file